# Getting key down event when form is hidden

Tags: c#, onkeydown

I'm making a memory game in C#, on the form a series of random characters will appear for a few seconds, then the form will hide and the user has to press to characters on his keyboard, the problem is that it dosen't register the key press when the form is hidden..

I tried `this.Focus();`

but it still dosen't work..

To hide the form I use:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Comment: Have a small form positioned off-screen to get the key presses when the primary form is hidden. Just give the (hidden) form the focus and put the code that reacts to the key presses in the code of this form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is difficult is you are essentially writing a key logger.
There is no reason to hide the form.  You can hide the text and avoid this issue.

Comment: That would depend on how you display it.  If it is in a control hide the control.  If you are drawing it directly on the canvas erase it and don't redraw it.